# Suggestions on ways to compare two files and show differences, maybe by rehosting a version comparion tool?

Tags: c#, comparison, rehosting

I'm trying to find a good way to have version comparison between two files (.docx files), where the files are compared and the differences are highlighted.  Eventually with the ability to output a report.

I was thinking maybe it's possible to rehost a comparison tool that is used by Team Foundation Server or something similar.  The documents will be hundreds of pages long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can u use 3rd party?  I have used Beyond Compare 3 which has really good file compare for xml stuff.

API was good in a sense that you could run batch scripts and it will dump the output in the format you want

Comment: Beyond compare is great. API is awesome as well. +1 for stealing my answer ;)